# Valid Induction Argument involving Closed Form for $\Gamma(1/2-n)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, induction, gamma-function

Given $\Gamma\left(\frac1{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$,
$$\sqrt{\pi}=\Gamma\left(\frac1{2}\right)=\Gamma\left(-\frac1{2}+1\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(-\frac1{2}\right)$$
and so $\Gamma\left(-\frac1{2}\right)=-2\sqrt{\pi}$
$$-2\sqrt{\pi}=\Gamma\left(-\frac1{2}\right)=\Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}+1\right)=-\frac{3}{2}\Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
and so $\Gamma\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{4\sqrt{\pi}}{3}$

And so I'm trying to determine a closed form working this way and prove it using induction.  The formula that I seem to be deducing is

$$\Gamma\left(\frac1{2}-n\right)=\frac{(-2)^n\sqrt{\pi}}{(2n-1)!!}$$

After showing base cases and assuming above is true for $n=k$, I work like this:

$$\Gamma\left(\frac1{2}-k\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}-(k+1)\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-(k+1)+1\right)=\frac{2k+1}{-2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-(k+1)\right)$$

Now I am in a position to solve for $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-(k+1)\right)$.  However, I feel like this is an invalid inductive argument.  I am used to doing induction problems where I plug in $k+1$ for $n$ as opposed to extracting it from the assumption step.  Yet this is how I was able to conjecture the closed form I have, from extraacting successive terms from the previous.  So my two question are these:

1)  Is the closed form correct?  I feel it is because given what I extracted, I can solve for $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-(k+1)\right)$ and get the formula for $k+1$.

2)  Is this a valid proof if it is correct (and I suppose even if it isn't, it this extraction method valid during induction proofs)?

Comment: with $(2n-1)!! = \prod_{k =0}^{n-1} (2k+1)$ the so called [odd double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial), yes

Comment: So it is okay to procede with an induction proof by extracting the $k+1$th term?  Awesome...thank you.

Comment: "extracting the $k+1$th term" means nothing, you are just using $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$ to express $\Gamma(1/2-k-1)$ in term of $\Gamma(1/2-k)$, why would it be a problem ? your proof by induction relies on $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$, that's all.

Comment: I see.  Thanks again!

Comment: the real interesting point, is : how do you know that $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,-1,-2,\ldots\}$ ?

Comment: that is a good question.  I'm not sure...wouldn't that just hold by definition of Gamma?

Comment: and analytic continuation. it is valid for $Re(z) > 0$ given the definition for $Re(z) > 0 $ : $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1} e^{-x} dx$. but for $Re(z) \le 0$, it is a matter of analytic continuation, proving $\Gamma(z)$ extends to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C} \setminus -\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Awesome.  That is a great point.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You can have this closed form too >$$\Gamma(1/2-n)=\frac{(-1)^n 2^{2n}n!\sqrt{\pi}}{(2n)!}\,,\quad n\in \mathbb {N} $$